# How to perform math on each value of multi-dimensional array using the sum of its column data?

Tags: php, arrays, math, multidimensional-array

I have a collection of "answers" (multi-dimensional array) which is extracted from a database.  I need to perform a calculation on each value so that I can show the results on a graph.

Here is some sample input:

```
$array = [
    'A1' => [1 => 1, 2 => 0, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0, 7 => 0, 8 => 0, 9 => 0, 10 => 0],
    'A2' => [1 => 1, 2 => 1, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0, 7 => 0, 8 => 0, 9 => 0, 10 => 0],
    'A3' => [1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0, 7 => 0, 8 => 0, 9 => 0, 10 => 0]
];
```

I want to calculate a percentage value from the multidimensional array using this kind of logic:

```
[A1] => Array( ([1]*100/sum([1]+[1]+[1]), [2]*100/sum([2]+[2]+[2]),..... )
[A2] => Array( ([1]*100/sum([1]+[1]+[1]), [2]*100/sum([2]+[2]+[2]),..... )
[A3] => Array( ([3]*100/sum([1]+[1]+[1]), [2]*100/sum([2]+[2]+[2]),..... )
```

How can I do this?

My desired output:

```
[
  'A1' => [1 => 50, 2 => 0,   3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0, 7 => 0, 8 => 0, 9 => 0, 10 => 0],
  'A2' => [1 => 50, 2 => 100, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0, 7 => 0, 8 => 0, 9 => 0, 10 => 0],
  'A3' => [1 => 0,  2 => 0,   3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0, 7 => 0, 8 => 0, 9 => 0, 10 => 0]
]
```

Comment: Do you want the average of each array or the average of all arrays?

Comment: thanks for reply.  am as asking like array [A1]array(first element / sum of first elements from 3 arrays)..

Comment: Would you explain a bit more the expected output? I believe this can be done easily with array_map, count and array_sum functions.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im question was edited. please have a look.

Comment: Seems nobody understands what are these values from. it makes anything but not average to my understanding of meaning of word 'average' in math. your shown expected result does not seem to match input data. if it does, i am unable to get how.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com sorry. question was edited.

Comment: that expected output is just horrible... why don't you come up with good example numbers and actual results?

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do, but your current "Answers" are fairly illogical. You currently have A1 (50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) but, that should probably be A1 (100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) or A1 (25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) 100 if only accounting for the value / total of A1, otherwise 25 if you want value / total of all arrays. However, it looks like what you might be trying to do (of the answers really are what you're looking for) is loop through ALL arrays, find the *highest* total, then get a percentage for each field based on that highest total. Which then might reflect your expected answers.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're trying to do. You want to sum all A(1)-A(N) for each column. So all A1[1], A2[1] A3[1] summed, then the result array would be A1[1] / A*[1]. That makes sense.

Comment: @DustinGraham  result array would be A1[1]*100 / sum[1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh, I see what you're trying to do now.

Try this

```
$totals = array();

// First get our totals.
foreach ($mainArray as $subKey => $subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $k => $v) {
        // Add the column to our total.
        $totals[$k] = isset($totals[$k]) ? $totals[$k] + $v : $v;
    }
}

$answers = array();
// Then build our answers.
foreach ($mainArray as $subKey => $subArray) {
    $answers[$subKey] = array();
    foreach ($subArray as $k => $v) {
        $answers[$subKey][$k] = ($v * 100) / $totals[$k];
    }
}

print_r($answers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dustin's answer was generating a lot of *Division by zero* warnings, so I thought I'd take the time to write up own answer.

Since the sample input array has subarrays of equal length, I'll not bother with `isset()` and simply trust that calling `array_column()` from the first row will access all available values.

In the first, `foreach()` `$v` is declared but not used because `array_column()` gathers it with the other vertical data.  `$column_totals` is a 1-dimensional array of sums.

Because individual calculations must be conducted on each element of the multi-dimensional input array, two loops are used.

Before performing the calculation, checking the "current value" and the "column sum value" 
for a zero value enables the quick return of `0` (and avoids Warnings); otherwise use the OP's formula.

*For those not familiar with the [Order of Operations](https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-bodmas.html), no parentheses are needed in the formula because reading the expression left-to-right will maintain the logic with `*` and `/`.

Code: (Demo)

```
$array = [
    'A1' => [1 => 1, 2 => 0, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0, 7 => 0, 8 => 0, 9 => 0, 10 => 0],
    'A2' => [1 => 1, 2 => 1, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0, 7 => 0, 8 => 0, 9 => 0, 10 => 0],
    'A3' => [1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0, 7 => 0, 8 => 0, 9 => 0, 10 => 0]
];

foreach (current($array) as $k => $v) {
    $column_totals[$k] = array_sum(array_column($array, $k));
}

foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        $result[$key][$k] = (!$v || !$column_totals[$k]) ? 0 : $v * 100 / $column_totals[$k];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'A1' => 
  array (
    1 => 50,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 0,
    4 => 0,
    5 => 0,
    6 => 0,
    7 => 0,
    8 => 0,
    9 => 0,
    10 => 0,
  ),
  'A2' => 
  array (
    1 => 50,
    2 => 100,
    3 => 0,
    4 => 0,
    5 => 0,
    6 => 0,
    7 => 0,
    8 => 0,
    9 => 0,
    10 => 0,
  ),
  'A3' => 
  array (
    1 => 0,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 0,
    4 => 0,
    5 => 0,
    6 => 0,
    7 => 0,
    8 => 0,
    9 => 0,
    10 => 0,
  ),
)
```